# Unity3d no Monobehaviour scripts in the file, or their names don't match the file name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello everyone I've been working on my first game and suddenly I got this error and cannot run the game, I already installed the new version of unity but it persists. I see it can be caused for several reasons but had no luck so far, do you know the most probable causes and how to fix it?

When I select the scripts the only one where I do not get this error is the following:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Code.States;
using Assets.Code.Interfaces;

public class StateManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private IStateBase activeState;

    void Start () 
    {
        activeState = new BeginState (this);
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if (activeState != null)
            activeState.StateUpdate();
    }
    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (activeState != null)
            activeState.ShowIt ();
    }
    public void SwitchState(IStateBase newState)
    {
        activeState = newState;
    }
}
```

But for example here I get the error:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Code.Interfaces;

namespace Assets.Code.States
{
    public class BeginState : IStateBase
    {
        private StateManager manager;

        public BeginState (StateManager managerRef)
        {
            manager = managerRef;
            Debug.Log ("Constructing BeginState");
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
        public void StateUpdate()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
            manager.SwitchState(new PlayState (manager));
        }

        public void ShowIt()
        {
            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 10, 150, 100), "Press to Play"))
            {
                Time.timeScale = 1;
                manager.SwitchState (new PlayState (manager));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And so on with every other script.

I've already installed a newer version of unity3d, uninstalled the antivirus, checked the file names but the error persists. I also do not have any class in a namespace..

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your script file is named exactly as the MonoBehaviour class it contains.

MyScript.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
}
```

Also, if your script file contains helper classes, make sure they are placed on the bottom of the file, never on top of the MonoBehaviour subclass.

Also, Unity will sometimes have problems when your MonoBehaviour classes are in namespaces. I don't know when exactly this happens, it simply does every now and then. Taking the class out of a namespace fixes the error.

Comment: BeginState is not a MonoBehaviour script, so the message "no MonoBehaviour scripts in the file" is valid. Is this really an error or just an info? When does the error occur?

Comment: I see what you mean, but the games does not run, nothing happens when I press play

Comment: There must be another reason for that. Make sure you clear your console. If there are still errors shown, then these are the ones you have to solve. If there are none, you will be able to start. If nothing happens then, there are runtime issues which may or may not spawn error messages. You'll have to debug, then.

Comment: If you have no errors, and nothing happens, then I'd suggest you attach a debugger, put breakpoints, and see what exactly it is that is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a strange variation of this issue, and did not see the solution posted anywhere else online.

**TLDR**

I had whitespace in the namespace for the classes which Unity could not identify as MonoBehaviours.

---

**Background**

I had the `No MonoBehaviour scripts in the file or ...` warning text on two script files in my project, one a MonoBehaviour, and the other a ScriptableObject.  Each issue had different symptoms:

**MonoBehaviour**

- The MonoBehaviour class was named like `MyMonoBehaviourService`.
- The script file was named `MyMonoBehaviourService.cs`
- The class was not partial, it had no nested types, nor any other types defined within the file.
- I could not attach `MyMonoBehaviourService` to a GameObject via the inspector, but I *could* via `gameObject.AddComopnents<MyMonoBehaviourService>()`.  This resulted in the script attached to the object, looking and behaving correctly.
- Upon entering PlayMode, I would get the error: `The referenced script (Unknown) on this Behaviour is missing!`
- After exiting PlayMode, the GameObject with the `MyMonoBehaviourService` attached would now say that it was missing.

**Scriptable Object**

- The ScriptableObject class was named like `MyScriptableServiceData`.
- The script file was named `MyScriptableServiceData.cs`.
- The class was not partial, it had no nested types, nor any other types defined within the file.
- I was able to create a `MyScriptableServiceData` via C# and save it using the `AssetDatabase`.
- I was then able to see and modify the properties using the inspector.
- Upon exiting and re-opening the project, the asset would say that its script was missing.

**Resolution**
Strangely enough, the issue was actually whitespace in the namespace for each class.  I mistakenly thought I was seeing word-wrapping but actually, there was a newline in the namespace.

```cs
namespace Appalachia.Prototype.KOC.Areas.DeveloperInterface.V01.Features.PerformanceProfiling.Services.
FPS
{
    public sealed class FPSProfilerService : MonoBehaviour
    {
    }
}
```

needed to be changed to this:

```cs
namespace Appalachia.Prototype.KOC.Areas.DeveloperInterface.V01.Features.PerformanceProfiling.Services.FPS
{
    public sealed class FPSProfilerService : MonoBehaviour
    {
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this causes an issue with MonoBehaviour/ScriptableObject detection but it really took a while for me to uncover.